# Keycloak configure with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

I develop Spring Boot Rest API project using JDBC and the database is PostgreSQL. I added authorization with Keycloak. I wanna use User Federation because I would like to use Users in my PostgreSQL DB. How can I use it and other ways not to use User Federation?

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem recently. I have different clients with different RDBMS, so I have decided to address this problem so that I could reuse my solution across multiple clients.

#### I published my solution as a multi RDBMS implementation (oracle, mysql, **postgresl**, sqlserver) to solve simple database federation needs, supporting bcrypt and several types of hashes.

Just build and deploy this solution on keycloak and configure it through the admin console providing jdbc connection string, login, password, the required SQL queries and the type of hash used.

Feel free to clone, fork or do whatever you need to solve your issue.

### GitHub repo:

https://github.com/opensingular/singular-keycloak-database-federation

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar development but with Oracle and JSF.

I created a project with three classes:

- one implementing UserStorageProvider, UserLookupProvider and CredentialInputValidator
- one implementing UserStorageProviderFactory
- one extending AbstractUserAdapter

Then I created another project which creates an ear file containing the jar file generated in the previous project plus the driver jar file (of PostgreSQL in your case) inside a lib folder.

Finally the ear file is copied in the /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/ folder of the Keycloak server and it gets autodeployed as a SPI. It's necessary to add this provider in the User federation section of the administration application of Keycloak.